# Dot product Matrices

Tags: matrix, python-3.x, dot-product

Hey so I was just wondering how to compute the the dotproduct of two matrices using a user defined function.

For example:

```
row(C,0)=[4, 1, 9]
col(D,0)=[2, 5, 1]
def dotProduct(x,y):


print(dotProduct(row(C,0), col(D,0)))
```

Should result in 22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def dotProduct(x,y):
    prod=0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        prod=prod+x[i]*y[i]
    return prod
```

Comment: `sum(xi * yi for xi, yi in zip(x, y))`